# Stepwise sampling in a tibble

Tags: r, random, dplyr, tibble

I am trying to simulate some data by sampling multiple steps.

The first step (create x) works fine.

In the second step, I want to create the variable y by sampling from different vectors based on the value of x.

My code runs without errors, but fails at what I am trying to achieve as it only samples one value for e.g., x == "A", and then reuses that value for all subsequent rows where x == "A". I want it to sample one time for each row where x == "A"

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

data <- tibble(
  x = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 10000, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), replace = TRUE),
  y = case_when(
    x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
    x == "B" ~ sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
    x == "C" ~ sample(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
  ))

unique(data$x)
[1] "C" "A" "B"

unique(data$y)
[1] "C1" "A2" "B3"
```

If the code works as intended `unique(data$y)` should return something similar to `[1] "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"`

I know the problem is the `size = 1` argument in sample(), but what can I replace it with? Removing it returns the error:

```
Error: `x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3))` must be length 100 or one, not 3
```

And I have tried `size = nrow(.data)` and `size=nrow(.)`, but that also returns error.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simple to understand if you divide this into steps

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(
   x = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 10000, 
                prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), replace = TRUE))

data <- data %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(
     x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = n(), 
               prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
     x == "B" ~ sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), size = n(), 
                 prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
     x == "C" ~ sample(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), size = n(), 
                prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
)) 

unique(data$y)
#[1] "C2" "B3" "A1" "C3" "B1" "C1" "B2" "A3" "A2"
```

---

Or if you want to continue your way you need to specify the `size` argument same as the one mentioned for `x` with `replace = TRUE`

```
data <- tibble(
  x = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 10000, 
            prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), replace = TRUE),
  y = case_when(
    x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = 10000, 
                  prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
    x == "B" ~ sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), size = 10000, 
                  prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
    x == "C" ~ sample(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), size = 10000, 
                  prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
  ))
```

Answer (score 2):

There maybe a simpler way but this stays close to your original code and works...

```
data <- tibble(
  x = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 10000, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarise(x= x, 
            y = case_when(
    x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
    x == "B" ~ sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
    x == "C" ~ sample(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)),
  ))
```

Comment: an additional comment .. @Sotos is a good explanation. And it would be more elegant I think just to work backwards creating `y` first by sampling `A1..C3` and then calculating `x` from `y`?

Comment: That is actually a much better idea. No need for `if` statements!

Comment: Maybe.. I feel on SO you should answer the specific query. but I often want to say 'are you sure you want to do that?'.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your elegant suggestion, and it would work better for the sample presented in this question.  However, the "real" data I am trying to simulate has more complicated relations between the groups, thereby making backward creation a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with vectorized functions and recycling. If you do it vectorized, it will recycle the same value. If you do it with a loop it works. For example,

```
v1 <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A')

#Vectorized ifelse
ifelse(v1 == 'A', sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)), NA)
#[1] "A3" "A3" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "A3" "A3"

#Not vectorized if/else with a loop,
sapply(v1, function(i) if (i == 'A') { sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)) }else {NA})
#   A    A    B    B    C    C    C    A    A 
#"A2" "A3"   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA "A2" "A1"
```